# Wordpress Memory fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress

i do have problem.
I am making site using wordpress and i've got memory error while i'm trying to enter all pages. Here is an error:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 87 bytes) in /wp-includes/meta.php on line 837`

I tried to incerease using `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` and `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');` but it didn't work, or maybe i've done something work. Does anybody know how to fix that?

Comment: if you using 134mb of memory, you did something terribly wrong. Check for bad plugin. Without more information, it's impossible answer to you.

Comment: All i done right now what making new pages and tables in TablePress (i have over 800 tables in tablepress) also i have something link 300 pages +-

Comment: If 134.21 mb of memory is not enough for entering a page, your solution is absolutely NOT ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'). You need to fix the underling issue.

Comment: So what should i do right now? That site is very important so i need to fix that

Comment: I can add new page but i can't check all created pages